# Multiple input value for single field - PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a query in PLSQL to search customer records from the tables. But still has some limitations. In the **&CUSTOMER_ID** Search field If I Put **IN%** OR **DL100056*** It will search All the details which start with IN or giving the exact DL details as output. I want to search multiple values like in the customer Id field I wanna search DL100056,DL1000365,DL1000652 likewise. But my current query not giving multiple outputs.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT CUSINFO.CUSTOMER_ID AS DEALER_CODE,
CUSINFO.name AS DEALER_NAME,
CUSINFO.CORPORATE_FORM AS FORM_OF_BUSINESS,
C.corporate_form_desc AS FORM_OF_BUSINESS_DESCRIPTION,
ifsapp.Customer_Info_Address_Api.Get_Address1(CUSINFO.customer_id,1) "ADDRESS 1",
ifsapp.Customer_Info_Address_Api.Get_Address2(CUSINFO.customer_id,1) "ADDRESS 2",
CREDTIN.credit_limit AS CREDIT_LIMIT,
CREDTIN.allowed_due_amount AS ALLOWED_DUE_AMOUNT,
CREDTIN.allowed_due_days AS ALLOWED_DUE_DAYS,
ORDERC.salesman_code AS SALESMAN_CODE,
BDA.name AS SALESMAN_NAME,
ORDERC.discount AS DISCOUNT,
(select LISTAGG(c.value,' / ') within group (order by c.value) from ifsapp.COMM_METHOD c 
 where c.method_id_db='PHONE' and c.identity=CUSINFO.customer_id ) "Phone",
(select LISTAGG(c.value,' / ') within group (order by c.value) from ifsapp.COMM_METHOD c 
 where c.method_id_db='MOBILE' and c.identity=CUSINFO.customer_id) "Mobile",
 (select LISTAGG(c.value,' / ') within group (order by c.value) from ifsapp.COMM_METHOD c 
where c.method_id_db='FAX' and c.identity=CUSINFO.customer_id) "Fax",
CUSINFO.identifier_reference as IDENTIFIER_REFERENCE


FROM
ifsapp.CUSTOMER_INFO CUSINFO
LEFT JOIN
ifsapp.CUSTOMER_INFO_ADDRESS CUSADD ON CUSINFO.customer_id=CUSADD.customer_id
LEFT JOIN
ifsapp.CUSTOMER_INFO_CONTACT CUSCONT ON CUSINFO.customer_id=CUSCONT.customer_id
LEFT JOIN
ifsapp.CUSTOMER_CREDIT_INFO_CUST CREDTIN ON CUSINFO.customer_id=CREDTIN.identity
LEFT JOIN
ifsapp.CUST_ORD_CUSTOMER_ENT ORDERC ON CUSINFO.customer_id=ORDERC.customer_id
LEFT JOIN
ifsapp.Comm_Method COMM ON CUSINFO.customer_id=COMM.customer_id
LEFT JOIN
ifsapp.CORPORATE_FORM C ON CUSINFO.corporate_form=C.CORPORATE_FORM
LEFT JOIN
ifsapp.SALES_PART_SALESMAN_LOV BDA ON ORDERC.salesman_code=BDA.salesman_code

WHERE CUSINFO.CUSTOMER_ID LIKE '&CUSTOMER_ID'
```

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question.

Comment: PL/SQL Developer and SQL Developer are desktop applications. Please don't tag them unless you have a specific issue with the way they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't work that way; one option is to use such a query (I don't have your tables so I used Scott's `DEPT`): it splits parameter values (separated by comma) into rows and uses them as a subquery. So, what you need is lines #3 - 5 (adjusted to your table / column name).

```
SQL> select deptno, dname, loc
  2  from dept
  3  where deptno in (select to_number(regexp_substr('&&par_deptno', '[^,]+', 1, level))
  4                   from dual
  5                   connect by level <= regexp_count('&&par_deptno', ',') + 1
  6                  )
  7  order by deptno;
Enter value for par_deptno: 10

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK

SQL> undefine par_deptno
SQL> /
Enter value for par_deptno: 20,40

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ..      ``WHERE CUSINFO.CUSTOMER_ID IN (select to_number(regexp_substr('&&CUSTOMER_ID', '[^,]+', 1, level)) 
from dual connect by level <= regexp_count('&&CUSTOMER_ID', ',') + 1)``

Comment: It says invalid Number

Comment: It doesn't for me (as you could have seen). I don't have your tables, but - looks like that it might be OK if you remove TO_NUMBER (if CUSTOMER_ID is a VARCHAR2 column and contains letters as well).

Answer (score 0):

1. please format your sql better, it is very difficult to understand the logic behind the query if its is unreadable.
2. You could try by using LIKE 'DL%'. This will look for all strings starting with DL. Another solution, if the code doesn't always start with 'DL', is using a substring on the code to get the first few characters, then adding '%'

hope this helped